# Spark java dataframe increment col

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to set a specific id value from which the increment will start. I need to generate a default value the first time I run the application. And when I restart the application, I need to set the initial id value. I need the increment to continue, not start at 0 or 1.

My code without passing an initial value looks like this:

```
dataset = dataset.withColumn(id, functions.monotonicallyIncreasingId())
```

I also tried using the row_number function, but I still don't understand how to set the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem First I created Integer maxValue = 0 ; On the second run, I pulled the maximum id value from the saved dataset and wrote it into maxValue. Next I wrote the code:
dataset = dataset.withColumn("id", functions.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("columnName")).plus(functions.lit(maxValue)));